# IISNode seems not working in IIS

Tags: node.js, angular, iis, iisnode

I am trying to host my Node.js in IIS.  I have build an application in Angular2.  Now, I was able to host the project and run it in IIS with IISnode installed.

Here is my web.config file.

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <handlers>
            <add name="iisnode" path="src/app/app.component.ts" verb="*" modules="iisnode" />
        </handlers>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="myapp">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="src/app/app.component.ts" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

This is the steps I followed in hosting NODE to IIS:
https://www.upnxt.com/blog/deploying-node-on-iis

But when I run the application I got this error:

```
Application has thrown an uncaught exception and is terminated:
C:\src\Angular2\BuyPracticeTest_AV4\src\app\app.component.ts:2
import { Service } from './app.service';
^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
```

it seems that **import** statement is not being recognized as a keyword. Or I really don't know.

I am new to this thing by the way.

Comment: update the post with the steps which you followed to host in IIS

Comment: done Aravind. updated post with the steps I followed in hosting node to iis.